# How to use the NestedBeanPropertyDefinition<T, V> in Vaadin 12.0.7?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin10

I'm currently trying to use a binder in Vaadin to access a nested property of an object. After googling a bit I found a reference example which sums up my problem quite well ([Original post](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8384)).:

Assume you have 2 beans:

```
public class Bean {
private SubBean sub;
// + getter setter
}
```

```
public class SubBean {
private String name;
// + getter setter
```

You think you should be able to do smthing like this:

```
Binder<Bean> binder = new Binder<>(Bean.class);
binder.bind(new TextField(), "sub.name");
```

How ever this results in an exception. Following the discussion of Vaadins repository this issue was closed by something called `NestedPropertyDefinitions` ([Potential solution referenced in the issue discussion which lead to closing the issue](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/8923)).

I was looking it up but merely found any information how to use it or how to easily access nested properties with the Vaadin binding system except for this one [Documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.7.2/com/vaadin/data/BeanPropertySet.NestedBeanPropertyDefinition.html).

Can anyone explain to me how to use `NestedPropertyDefinitions` ?

Comment: IIRC, `binder.bind(new TextField(), "sub.name");` is just a short form for `binder.forField(new TextField()).bind("sub.name");`. Are you absolutely sure that one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error was on my side! I updated my question. Would be great if Vaadin devs could add an nested example on this page: https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder.html

Comment: I think this is mentioned 3 sub-menu points further down: [Binding Beans to Forms](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-beans.html). Well, not mentioned with words, but used in the first code sample. And yes `NestedPropertyDefinitions` is only used internally. When binding with a property-name string, it looks if that string has a `.` in it. if yes, it will automatically create and return a NestedPropertyDefinitions

Comment: Ah you're right. How could I not find this one? Thank's for your help and providing insights, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this:

```
binder.forField(new TextField()).bind("sub.name")
```

works in Vaadin 12.0.7. It does for grids and binders as well. Apparently there is no need to use `NestedPropertyDefinitions` to achieve nested bindings. I had a bug on my backend side which caused an error that made me assume the binding did not work properly. So I still can't tell if there is another way of achieving this or what `NestedPropertyDefinitions`do but I'd assume that they are used by Vaadin internally.

According to Cashbees comment `NestedPropertyDefinitions` is only used internally and how to deal with nested properties is indirecetly referenced in this [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-beans.html).